# azure dev ops test plan order in execute section

Tags: azure-devops

In azure dev ops in test plans define you can manage order of your test cases. However in execute they are shown randomly. Am i missing something or whats the reason for ordering your test cases, but they are shown randomly? Is there anyway to show them in order by default?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Test Points in **Execute** tab are sorted by Test Case order in **Define** tab.

> Is there anyway to show them in order by default?

You can navigate to **Define** tab and move **Pre-requisites** test case before **Create new account** test case.

Then they will show in order by default.

**Update:**

The Test Points in **Execute** tab  default view is ordered by Test Case ID order.

[image]

You can add **Test Case ID** column and check Test Case ID.

Comment: But that is exactly what I have done. If you look in the screenshots, you can see that execute does not show the order defined.

Comment: @ThomasSegato. Thanks for your remind. I can get your point. The default view of Execute tab is order by Test Case ID. In this case, you will see the issue you encountered.

Comment: I wonder if we should make a support case. As the ordering does not make much sense then, if it is of no use?

Comment: You can create a feedback ticket in  Developer Community : https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/report?space=21&entry=problem to report the issue